# Permutations sign and determinant computation

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

**Example** of determinant computation Wikipedia

[image]

I have printed screen this from Wikipedia. I studied linear algebra but we did not spend time working on the mechanism behind the determinant computation. As I was reading this article a doubt arose.

**Question:**

$sign(123)=1=sign(132)$. Why does (123) and (132) different signs if they are cycles with the same length?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those are not cycles. $[1,3,2]$ is the transposition two-cycle $(2 3)$.

Comment: @Somos           How do I read$ [1,3,2]$ as the two-cycle$ (23)$. What is the general rule you applied?

Comment: Please read Wikipedia article [Cyclic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation).